# whitelist cloudflare Ips with having ngx_http_realip_module enabled

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I´ve a website on nginx with cloudflare running and want to block all requests which are not coming trough cloudflare.

Normally i´d whitelist the nginx IPs in the nginx configuration and deny all other.

But i´ve ngx_http_realip_module running which sets the X-Forward-For Address( which is the real Ip from the Visitor ) as request-IP and so the request gets denied.

Is there a way to get this whitelist work without deactivating the ngx_http_realip_module? Also this whitelist should only apply to requests to nginx and not to other services

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I came up with that can be done with nginx by itself requires nginx version 1.9.7 or higher.

You can use the [ngx_http_geo_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) to identify and block responses for any ip's that aren't cloudflare ip's.

Using this geo block.

```
geo $realip_remote_addr $cloudflare_ip {
    default          0;
    103.21.244.0/22  1;
    103.22.200.0/22  1;
    103.31.4.0/22    1;
    104.16.0.0/13    1;
    104.24.0.0/14    1;
    108.162.192.0/18 1;
    131.0.72.0/22    1;
    141.101.64.0/18  1;
    162.158.0.0/15   1;
    172.64.0.0/13    1;
    173.245.48.0/20  1;
    188.114.96.0/20  1;
    190.93.240.0/20  1;
    197.234.240.0/22 1;
    198.41.128.0/17  1;
    2400:cb00::/32   1;
    2405:8100::/32   1;
    2405:b500::/32   1;
    2606:4700::/32   1;
    2803:f800::/32   1;
    2c0f:f248::/32   1;
    2a06:98c0::/29   1;
}
```

You can then add this to your server block.

```
if ($cloudflare_ip != 1) {
    return 444;
}
```

Which will close the connection for any connections not originating from a `$cloudflare_ip`.

This works because I'm using `$realip_remote_addr` in the geo block which keeps the original client address when using `real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP`.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post a QA and found this question which was the same, but I did not find it with a google search. So avoiding a duplicate and still sharing the knowledge

To achieve that, you can use the [geo block](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) with the [`$realip_remote_addr`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) variable

Here is a full configuration file

```
geo $realip_remote_addr $cloudflare {
  default false;
# https://www.cloudflare.com/ips
# IPv4
  173.245.48.0/20 true;
  103.21.244.0/22 true;
  103.22.200.0/22 true;
  103.31.4.0/22 true;
  141.101.64.0/18 true;
  108.162.192.0/18 true;
  190.93.240.0/20 true;
  188.114.96.0/20 true;
  197.234.240.0/22 true;
  198.41.128.0/17 true;
  162.158.0.0/15 true;
  104.16.0.0/13 true;
  104.24.0.0/14 true;
  172.64.0.0/13 true;
  131.0.72.0/22 true;
# IPv6
  2400:cb00::/32 true;
  2606:4700::/32 true;
  2803:f800::/32 true;
  2405:b500::/32 true;
  2405:8100::/32 true;
  2a06:98c0::/29 true;
  2c0f:f248::/32 true;
# Generated at Thu Apr  6 11:05:36 CEST 2023
}
# https://www.cloudflare.com/ips
# IPv4
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 104.24.0.0/14;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
# IPv6
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
# Generated at Thu Apr  6 11:05:36 CEST 2023
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

Then in your `server` block you can simply use:

```
if ($cloudflare = false) {
    return 403;
}
```

Allowing you to filter all non cloudflare requests on a vhost basis (if some vhosts are on cloudflare and some not for instance)

With that in mind we can create an `/etc/cron.weekly/nginx-cloudflare-ips` script to regenerate this `/etc/nginx/conf.d/cloudflare.conf` file every week

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

cf_ips() {
echo "# https://www.cloudflare.com/ips"

for type in v4 v6; do
echo "# IP$type"
curl -sL "https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-$type/" | sed "s|^|set_real_ip_from |g" | sed "s|\$|;|g"
echo
done

echo "# Generated at $(LC_ALL=C date)"
}
CF_IPS=$(cf_ips)
(echo "geo \$realip_remote_addr \$cloudflare {" && echo "  default false;" && echo "$CF_IPS" | sed "s|set_real_ip_from| |g" | sed "s|;| true;|g" && echo "}" && echo "$CF_IPS" && echo "real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;" && echo "real_ip_recursive on;") > /etc/nginx/conf.d/cloudflare.conf
# reload Nginx
systemctl reload nginx
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not block these in iptables instead of in Nginx? Block the traffic before it even needs to be processed by Nginx (which will save resources).

If you're going that route I'd be happy to share my iptables config (v4 and v6) for how to do it.

Comment: can you post it?

Comment: One reason to block in nginx instead of iptables is that there may be hosted some sites on the same maschine that do not use Cloudflare.